# Vb.net cant transfer data with image from access to excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access

Hi is there a way to transfer access database with image to excel ? Since my image using ole object.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If DataGridView1.RowCount = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry nothing to export into excel sheet.." & vbCrLf & "Please retrieve data in datagridview", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
    Dim I, j, iC As Short
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim xlApp As New excel.Application

    Try
        Dim excelBook As excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim excelWorksheet As excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), excel.Worksheet)
        xlApp.Visible = True

        rowsTotal = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        colsTotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        With excelWorksheet
            .Cells.Select()
            .Cells.Delete()
            For iC = 0 To colsTotal
                .Cells(1, iC + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Columns(iC).HeaderText
            Next
            For I = 0 To rowsTotal - 1
                For j = 0 To colsTotal
                    .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
                    .Shapes.AddPicture("C:\pic.jpg", MsoTristate.msofalse, msotristate.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45) <-I just add this to transfer the image
                Next j
            Next I
            .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 12
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
            .Cells.Select()
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
            .Cells(1, 1).Select()

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        'RELEASE ALLOACTED RESOURCES
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
        xlApp = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

If the data doesnt have any picture then it can be transfered but with image it just not working... I been following some walkthrough and i just add that code to allow picture transfer.

The imports thst i use:

```
Imports system.data.oledb
Imports microsoft.office.core
imports excel = microsoft.office.interop.excel
```

Comment: When you say "Just not working" what does that mean?  Are you getting some exception perhaps?  Is the data other than the picture being inserted? No data inserted at all?  Notice you've got the image file name hard coded, is that a valid image?

Comment: Its that the whole data wont transfered if there an image. If there an image then only the previous data before the picture is exported to excel. Is there a way to get the file without the object name hardcoded ?.

Comment: Well, looking at the code, if it works without the .Shapes.AddPicture, I can't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't with adding the picture.  Are you sure the picture isn't being inserted over top of the data obscuring it from view?

Comment: Not really.... In the view the picture is in there but it wont transfered at all. My export stopped right before the image so only the first database is inserted. Im gonna try using new database to see if there a different..

Comment: What do you mean "database"  You're reading rows from a DataGridView.  What exactly are you expecting a new Database to do?  And Code just doesn't stop, it will provide with feedback telling you what is going on.  Where exactly is it stopping?

Comment: Its stop before the image being inserted.. After i read the error and check, apparently the file is not found on the directory. After i add it now its working... Sry for troubling you sir